# Popup in the onDestroy Method

Tags: android

i want a popup with a "ok" button in the onDestroy method.

i tried this, but i didn´t work out:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setMessage("BlaBla!").setPositiveButton("OK",dialogClickListener).show();
}


DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
    {
        switch (which)
        {
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
            //DO nothing
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Would be great if you could help me!!

Thanks

Comment: What means didn't wokout? but why in onDestroy() method? it makes no sence for me.

Answer (score 1):

It is wrong approach to display popup in onDestroy.. it is not going to work..
You can display confirmation popup while exiting from activity, say by overriding Back Press..

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the AlertDialog you are creating is being destroyed with the MainActivity onDestroy() is being called on. You probably want to create your alert dialog in onStop() instead. See the Activity lifecycle: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

2 things come to mind start a new activity or use Toast